# Bootstrap 3 is not letting me use CSS/JQuery image replacement on hover with transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

UPDATE: My project is now on [Github](http://github.com/andrealeigh/Resume). Here is the [site](http://andrealeigh.github.io/Resume/) (Btw it's not finished!)

I am trying to create the following effect on my website:

I want to have social media images that, when hovered, will be replaced with different images via a slow, smooth transition. I was able to successfully get this to work in a simple test environment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <style>

      img.one {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 10;
      }

      img.two {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
     }

  </style>
```

```
<ul class="gallery">
    <ul class="gallery">
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/AndreaLeigh111" target="_blank"><img class="one" src="images/icon-twitter.png" alt=""/> <img class="two" src="images/icon-twitter-hover.png" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.one").hover(
      function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },
      function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
  });
```

It worked fine in the browser and everything was rainbows and unicorns.

Then, I tried to replicate this in my current project, which I am building with SCSS and Bootstrap 3 (I know, not 3.3, but I don't have the strength right now). Here are snippets of my code:

```
     <div class="container-fluid" id="contact">
      <div class="row">
         <img src="images/CONTACT.svg" class="img-responsive" alt="CONTACT"/>
         <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
               <a href="https://twitter.com/AndreaLeigh111" target="_blank"><img class="one" src="images/icon-twitter.png" alt=""/> <img class="two" src="images/icon-twitter-hover.png" alt="" /></a>
            </div>    
         </div>

         <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-12">
           <p class="text-center">
             BUILT WITH A CAT ON MY LAP. ANDREA L. WILLIAMSON &copy; 2014.
           </p>
         </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--more html code here, but not relevant-->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.one").hover(
          function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
        },
          function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
        });
      });

  </script>
```

Here is my SCSS:

```
   div#contact.container-fluid div.row {
     background-color: black;
     div.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1 div.col-sm-2.col.sm-offset-1 {
        a img.one {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
          z-index: 10;
        }

        a img.two {
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          top: 0;
        }
     }

     .col-md-8 {
       color: rgb(108, 111, 118);
       font-family: 'robotoblack', sans-serif;
       padding-top: 50px;
       padding-bottom: 15px;
     }
   }
```

The first image fades away with the nice slow transition, sweet! But the second image is positioned directly under the first instead of in the same position. For some reason my SCSS is not taking. Compass is running, no errors. "Inspect element" shows none of my new SCSS code (it's not even there and crossed out). I've checked the generated CSS file, the new code is in there. I can change others things in SCSS and the changes show up in the browser.

So, what gives? any ideas on what voodoo Bootstrap is doing? Or if you don't have any ideas, but have successfully made image replacement with a transition happen via Bootstrap/SCSS, how did you do it?

THANK YOU INTERNET

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to show us more? Problems with image switching on a live system could also derive from the browser having to download the image first which takes some time but based on your description this seems not to be the problem here...

Comment: Yes! I am working on trying to get all of the code up with images and SCSS code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following up on Twitter, the selector in the stylesheet was incorrect.

```
div#contact.container-fluid div.row div.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1 div.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1 a img.one {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

div#contact.container-fluid div.row div.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1 div.col-sm-2.col-sm-offset-1 a img.two {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Should have been:

```
div#contact.container-fluid div.row div.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1 div.col-sm-2 a img.one {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

div#contact.container-fluid div.row div.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1 div.col-sm-2 a img.two {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

I suggested alternative ways of achieving the same effect as well.